# PHP/Smarty Remove Everything after character

Tags: php, html, smarty

I want to remove everything after the underline and I have this:

```
{$result.searchname|escape:"htmlall"|replace:".":" "|strstr:'_':true}
```

which works well so far. My problem is now that by

```
|strstr:'_':true
```

all the HTML title who do not have a underscored in title are no longer displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl

`{'hello_world'|regex_replace:'/_.*/':''}` will print "hello"

Also, I feel quite strongly about their note and would recommend you perform the string processing before the data is assigned to smarty where possible:

> Although Smarty supplies this regex convenience modifier, it is
>   usually better to apply regular expressions in PHP, either via custom
>   functions or modifiers. Regular expressions are considered application
>   code and are not part of presentation logic.

Comment: I am sorry but I have to quest again how can I do this in the other directen so everything get removed before the underline + the underline it self ?

I read the link above and try some combinations but my understanding about missing.

Can someone help and explain what the symbols exactly do .

Comment: Ok this work for me

`|regex_replace:'/^.*_/':''}`

but now have an other problem with it, I have string like

`_{{AEfV_axNgh}}`

Need this `AEfV_axNgh` as output, Ideas ?

Comment: Solution for me:
`{'_{{AEfV_axNgh}}' |regex_replace:'/^.*{{/':''|replace:"}}":" "}` will print "AEfV_axNgh"

Comment: `|regex_replace:'/.*\{\{|\}\}.*/':''` should also work for a single pattern and get `foo_{{AEfV_axNgh}}_bar` and leave `AEfV_axNgh`